# "D'accordo" or "daccordo": How should I spell it?

Tags: spelling

Which one is the correct way to spell it?

> Io sono **daccordo**

or

> Io sono **d'accordo** *(with the apostrophe)*

Comment: They, as far as I know, 'daccordo' isn't an Italian word, though.

Comment: Are we sure that questions like this, which can be answered by simply looking up a word in a dictionary, are appropriate for SE?

Comment: @TheycallmeTrinity: Right, I'll pose the issue in Meta.

Answer (score 7):

The one with the apostrophe is correct, see the [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/unite-separate) site, even tough on the same page the spelling '**daccordo**' is listed as a less common but still correct form.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure why the DOP (which is the source the Crusca site quotes) included, even as a rare form, “daccordo”, but none among Treccani, Zingarelli and Devoto-Oli dictionaries admit it (nor, for what's worth, would I, as an Italian native).

Comment: yep, same here.

Answer (score 4):

The origin is from ‘di accordo’; although the phrase is just a single adverb, it's customary to write it with an apostrophe. Other compound adverbs or conjunctions are normally written as single words, but, as ‘tutt'al più’–‘tuttalpiù’ or ‘per lo più’–‘perlopiù’ show, there is no general consensus about this.

Personally I'd never write ‘daccordo’.